# I am trying to draw a line using an svg libraray in Java , but I am not able to create OMSVGPathSegList

Tags: java, svg, gwt

My `gwt` code in `java` looks like this

```
OMSVGDocument doc = OMSVGParser.currentDocument();
OMSVGSVGElement svg =  doc.createSVGSVGElement();
OMSVGPathElement path = doc.createSVGPathElement();
OMSVGPathSegList segs = path.getPathSegList();
```

the return value `segs` is `null` and hence I am not able to use `OMSVGPathSegList` to draw.
`Java` Version = `1.7` and `gwt version` is `2.8.2`. Is this a version problem?

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the version of svg-lib , java and gwt. The following combinations worked for me `java 1.8` , `gwt 2.8.2` , `svg-lib 0.5.14` .